# multiprocessing.Pool, does not affect the classes variables permanently

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I am using multiprocessing.Pool to distribute the work of a method on several processors. When I add something to a dictionary, it is lost after the method is executed. Why is that? And how to circumvent it?

```
from multiprocessing import Pool


class Agent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.test_dict = {}

    def apply(self, num):
        # something very processor intensive here
        self.test_dict[num] = num
        print 'inside ', self.test_dict

def F(x):
    agent, i = x
    return agent.apply(i)

class SeriesInstance(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.agent = Agent()
        self.F = F

    def run(self):
        p = Pool()

        for i in range(5):
            out = p.map(F, [(self.agent, i),])

            print 'outside', self.agent.test_dict


        p.close()
        p.join()

        return out

if __name__ == '__main__':
    SeriesInstance().run()
```

the output is this, but outside should be equal to inside

```
inside  {0: 0}
outside {}
inside  {1: 1}
outside {}
inside  {2: 2}
outside {}
inside  {3: 3}
outside {}
inside  {4: 4}
outside {}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python multiprocessing: How do I share a dict among multiple processes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6832554/python-multiprocessing-how-do-i-share-a-dict-among-multiple-processes)

Comment: In your real code, which part of this is doing processor-intensive work?

Comment: no the real code is to long to be posted here the processor intensive task would be in the apply function of agent.

Answer (score 1):

Please check [Sharing state between processes](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) and read the section **Server process**. It appears that you have to create a manager and use that manager to create the `dict` instances used in your `Agent` class.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager

def f(d, l):
    d[1] = '1'
    d['2'] = 2
    d[0.25] = None
    l.reverse()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Manager() as manager:
        d = manager.dict()
        l = manager.list(range(10))

        p = Process(target=f, args=(d, l))
        p.start()
        p.join()

        print(d)
        print(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

Noctis-Skytower has one solution, but the more general answer is that you shouldn't be trying to share state between processes unless you have a good reason.

To understand why the behavior is what it is, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12978919/377366) to a similar question. When you make changes to the object in another process, you are actually making changes to a *copy* of that object. I.e. your object gets recreated in the sub process rather than used directly.

In the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html#pipes-and-queues) you can see that you want to basically be passing simple messages instead of heavy objects. That might mean you need to redesign your workflow.